# Point to Point Connection Between Two Hosts

Tags: linux-networking, ethernet, host, networking, p2p

I am trying to set up a point to point connection between two Linux host machines. I've connected both of them with crossover cable, but they can't ping each other. Here are the configurations for each laptop:

**Laptop 1**

```
(eth0 configuration)
IP Address - 128.110.1.6
Subnet Mask - 255.255.255.240
Gateway - 128.110.1.1
```

**Laptop 2**

```
(eth0 configuration)
IP address - 128.110.1.1
Subnet Mask - 255.255.255.240
Gateway - 128.110.1.6
```

Is there something that I'm missing here? How can I establish connectivity between the two laptops?

**Edit-1**: I ran the `'arp -a'` command and received the following output:

**Laptop 1**

```
? (128.110.1.1) at <incomplete> on eth0
```

**Laptop 2**

```
? (128.110.1.6) at <incomplete> on eth0
```

I'm guessing these entries in the ARP table might be due to the failed pings.

**Edit-2**: I discovered that one of the laptops has a bridge enabled which was previously used with a usb-to-ethernet adapter interface as `eth1` and the built in ethernet interface is `eth0`. Not sure if that would affect anything though. Following the suggestion to run `ethtool` produced the following output:

**Laptop 1**

```
[root@link_3 doctor]# /sbin/ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Link detected: yes
[root@link_3 doctor]# /sbin/ethtool eth1
Settings for eth1:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  Not reported
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Speed: 10Mb/s
        Duplex: Half
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Link detected: no
```

**Laptop 2**

```
[root@hitl3 doctor]# /sbin/ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
        Link detected: yes
```

Comment: Sorry to ask stupid questions, but I take it that neither box is running a firewall (`iptables -L -n -v`)?

Comment: is the link on the network card detected? what about the speed they are working at? you can check with `ethtool <ethX>`

Comment: @MadHatter - Firewall and SELinux are both disabled and there's nothing in the iptables.

Comment: The ethtool suggestion was a good one. Let's see the result. And the received packet count from `ifconfig` - whether or not it goes up while you're attempting a ping would be interesting.

Comment: You don't need to define the gateway address as the other machine.  That's not really right but won't prevent it working.  On Laptop 1 set the ethernet configuration to eth0 since eth1 doesn't have a link but eth0 does.

Comment: The first ethtool just prints those 2 lines of output? That's really odd. What driver is running that eth0? And does ethtool report that the link goes down if you unplug the cable?

Comment: Do you have ping enabled and are the cards giving led status orange/green both?

Comment: I find it odd that laptop detected a link at 1Gbps while the other card only supports 100Mbps, though I don't remember what should happen in this case. What happens if you use `ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full` on laptop 2?

Comment: Transfer your enthernet config to eth0 on laptop 1.  What Linux distro are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that at least one of the Ethernet ports is GigE. Otherwise you might need a crossover cable.

Comment: Actually, I am using a crossover cable. I updated my question to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

You may have network cards which don't auto-detect the cable type (auto-MDIX) - before this feature became widely available we would make up [crossover cables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) for this or [use an adapter](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/utp-crossover-adapter-male-to-female-a07ab).

Comment: I am using a crossover cable. Forgot to mention that in my question.

Comment: Does it work? Do the systems connect when you use patch cables and a hub?